# 2 threads accessing at the same time to a synchronized function

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

i have a program that automatically generate threads depending on the number of cores of the cpu (2 in my case because im running the program in a VM)

I have a function named createTable wich creates a table if it doesn't exist, the problem is that i have multiple threads so the IF statment could be unusefull, i tried to use synchronized but i had the same result

```
public synchronized void createTable(Utils utils, String tableName, RowSerializable row) {
   if(!utils.getClient().tableExists(tableName)) {
       this.table = utils.generateTable(tableName, row);
       this.fieldsNames = utils.getNamesOfColumns(table);
   }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: can you give more details ? A synchronized method is enough if the same instance of the underlying object is shared between the threads. Is it your case ?

Comment: How many objects that contain this code do you create?  The synchronization is going to be at the *object* level.  If each thread creates a separate object, there will be no synchronization.

Comment: Are you calling the method from two different objects ? If yes in that case it will take the lock on two different objects, hence will allow both the threads to access this method code. Or else take the class level lock. (make the method static)

Comment: The method is called only from one object @AndrewHenle but is called from a code wich its not mine, I'm using Apache Flink API

Comment: Yes, it is the same instance @davidxxx

Comment: @A.Vadillo How do you *know* it's the same instance of the object?  A quick test would be to synchronize on a static object instead.

Comment: How are your threads sharing the instance where `createTable(Utils,String,RowSerializable)` is define ? I would guess, if the `synchronized` keywork is not working that these threads are not using the same instance, so `this` is different (the instance use to synchronize the method) and the lock (synchronized) is not set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably use multiple instances otherwise you would have not a problem of synchronization on the method access that is synchronized on a instance.

To solve your problem you could make the synchronization on a static field shared by all instances.

Add a static `Object` in the class and make the synchronization on, it should solve the problem of access concurrent:

```
   public class YourClassThatHasTheProblem {
   ...
   private static final Object lock = new Object();
   ... 
    public void createTable(Utils utils, String tableName, RowSerializable row) {
      synchronized (lock) {
        if(!utils.getClient().tableExists(tableName)) {
          this.table = utils.generateTable(tableName, row);
          this.fieldsNames = utils.getNamesOfColumns(table);
         }
       }
  }
 ...
}
```

If it doesn't solve your problem it means that the problem doesn't come from the  code synchronization only but because you perform in another class or method a similar processing and that is not synchronized with this call. So it creates a side effect with the `createTable()` invocation.

Comment: I would guess too, I would prefer to see how he failed to share the same instance between Threads. But off course, a static fields is simple and works.

Comment: I think it works! I'll keep testing the program. Thanks

Comment: @AxelH Indeed, I understand but I am not sure that the OP knows really how the resource that creates the race condition is instantiated. If the solution works it could also help the OP to be aware that he uses multiple instances and then study its code to understand.

Comment: @A.Vadillo Great if it helped you :)

Comment: @davidxxx fully agree with you. And in the worst scenario, this will help readers that don't necessary have the hand on the initialisation process of those instance.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that 2 threads are accessing `createTable` method, and I'll try to explain.

This method defined `synchronized`, which means that the object it synchronized on is `this`.
So my guess is that in you program, 2 threads may access `createTable` because there are two different objects, that each `createTable` synchronize on.

Therefore, if 2 threads want to create new table with the same name - it is possible.

NOTE: this analysis is based on the information you gave, if you think it is unlikely, please provide more information and I'll try to help.

Comment: This [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15250419/4391450) could show what you explained and a bit more ( static)

Comment: It is the same instance so both threads tries to create the table. The first one creates it and the second throw an exception

Comment: @ AxelH - if you meant me, I removed my comment the second I posted it exactly because what you said